# How do I prevent Google from serving a cached version of my site?

Tags: seo, google, cache, google-cache, noarchive

From what I understand I can tell Google to remove pages from their archive if I add the header:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" contents="NOARCHIVE" />
```

But won't this also remove the page from search results? I only want the "Cached" link removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, it will not remove your site from the listings, only from the archive.  So your NOARCHIVE idea is correct.  You can read more about how Google treats all of this on Google's own blog: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/02/robots-exclusion-protocol.html

Comment: That's a great catchall of nofollow, nocache, nosnippet usage. So I could specify google with `<META NAME="GOOGLEBOT" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">` as opposed to using a name of `ROBOTS`. THANKS!